# not statement in CSS? Or way around? (superfish)

Tags: javascript, html, css, superfish

I have tried finding this on the net had no luck.

I'm using superfish dropdown and I need the top li to be rounded, but not li's with ul's inside, if you see here this is the test page where its demo'd:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UdvBC/

But i need to say sort of.. only apply the rounding on the top li not the ones in the dropdown, is this doable?

Thanks :)

Comment: CSS = Cascading Style Sheets. So you can cascade styles depeing on it parent  `.TopMenu{ rounded} ` ; `.TopMenu.SubMenu1{notRounded}` works well and cascades across the site.. Just make sure the HTML markup is `<ul><li class="TopMenu">....<ul><li Class=SubMenu1> ....</li></ul> ... </li></ul>`

Comment: The "cascade" in CSS doesn't mean what you think it means...

Comment: Please do not remove links from your question after it's solved, especially if there's no sample code provided in your question, as then your question will be meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking to use the :first-child selector from what I gather...

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

It allows you to apply special CSS to the very first item.  <strike>Just make sure to apply the first-child selector AFTER the styles applying to all items, so as to prevent overriding the first-child properties.</strike>

Example:

```
ul li { background: red; }
ul li:first-child { background: blue; }
```

<strike>Putting it in the opposite order would override the first-child CSS.</strike>

Edit: Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Your statement about ordering of the rules is incorrect. There is no need to apply it after the styles applying to all items, as the addition of `:first-child` will make the selector more specific, preventing `ul li` from overriding it.

Comment: Just an update, I used this technique and it works perfecto thank you very much for this!

Comment: Oh come on @Metalfrog, seriously. Haters gonna hate.

Comment: @MetalFrog: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120025/will-i-be-downvoted-for-giving-a-w3schools-link

Comment: Remember that it will only work with CSS3 browsers. Any older ones will degrade to basic styles so test it in IE6,IE7 as they are the worst

Comment: @ppumkin: `:first-child` is not a CSS3 selector. It is a CSS2 selector, and as such IE7 and IE8 support it just fine in standards mode.

Comment: Note: For :first-child to work in IE8 and earlier, a <!DOCTYPE> must be declared

Comment: "Despite w3schools.com having a sullied reputation among many, it does serve as an "OK" reference point."

That's the comment I made in one of my previous posts.  I'm well aware of w3fools.com and have been for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

CSS cannot really accept *not* statements like that, so I'd suggest defining separate classes for the two types of `li`'s.

Comment: Just decided to look at my history on SO and saw this thread.  10 years is a long time and now we DO have a :not CSS selector.  Crazy, right?  :)

Comment: @Minja yep, I got back into web design after many years, and html and css have so much new native functionality now.